# Regular expression about ternary string

Tags: regex, state-machine

Ok I just realized what I am asking for.

What is the regular expression for all binary numbers?

Would have thought I could google it but maybe I'm really bad at google.

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For the regex, I would try

```
[01]*
```

That matches any combination of integers from the set [0,1].

To get the hang of regular expressions, I would try out a online regex interpreter, such as http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html or http://rubular.com/ . They let you input test strings to test if your regular expression matches or not.

Comment: Ok yes I came to the same conclusion actually a minute ago so I think thats correct. Thank you.